# Conditional inequality statements on two columns of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, inequality

For two conditional equality statements on two columns of a pandas DataFrame `df`, we would normally use

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] == 0.9 & (df['col2'] == 1)]
```

How to do the same for conditional inequality statements?

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 0.9) & (df['col2'] > 1)]
```

The above gives an error I think because of the float `0.9`

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'
```

More specifically, the error appears when `df.col1` is used in place of `df['col1']`, etc

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: is col1 a name of function ?

Comment: no it's just the column name

Comment: does `df['col1'] > 0.9` give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to add the outside parentheses.

Instead of this:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 0.9) & (df['col2'] > 1)]
```

Try this:

```
df.loc[((df['col1'] > 0.9) & (df['col2'] > 1))]
```